# What is the recommended pattern to design a function that can implement multiple algorithms for S4 class in R?

Tags: r, r-s4

I have an object of `class S4` "MyOb" and a generic function "MyFun". I would like to implement multiple different algorithms for MyFun to process MyOb and be able to select the algorithm I want by specifying the "type" in the generic function. Type would be an argument of MyFun and would be just a character (string): "Algo1", "Algo2"...

However, each algorithm would require different arguments. I have started has indicated in the code below but then I am not sure how to continue, should I have a `switch` in the `setMethod` function that redirect to other separate functions ?

```
setGeneric("MyFun", function(x, type, ...) standardGeneric("MyFun"))

setMethod("MyFun", c("MyOb", "character"), function(x, type, ...){

       switch()??? #to Algo1, Algo2, ....
})

Algo1<-function(x, M, N){ #blabla }
Algo2<-function(x, F, G, H){ #blablabla }
```

Ideally, I like to end up with something like the function `baseline` in the `baseline` R package, with
`MyFun.Algo1`, `MyFun.Algo2` being the different function and `MyFun` the generic one...

I have been looking for this type of pattern but could not find any tutorial...

Any hint, advice, recommendation would be appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I just check: is it assumed that the user will tell which of `algo1` or `algo2` to use, or can it be inferred based on the class of `x`?

Comment: The class of x is always the same. The user has to specify the algo to use with type: type="algo1", type="algo2", etc.

Comment: If the class of `x` is always the same, why is `myFun` a generic function at all?

Comment: Well, that's a good point. It's my first package and obviously I am still learning, I followed [this tutorial](https://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/s4Classes.html#creating-methods) where they specifically mention: "...if the name of a function has not been defined, the name must first be reserved using the setGeneric function." But what you say makes much more sense to me, what is the point of defining a generic if x is always the same S4 class... When I run a check() with the answer below, I have a Warning that complains about the fact that algo1 and algo2 are S3 methods...

Comment: There is not normally a need to "reserve" function names: each package gets its own namespace so it doesn't matter much if another package defines a function with the same name as yours. If you don't need to export the function, it doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you probably want to only have `x` as the signature of your function (you don't want a different method based on the class of `type`, for example). So you should start with

```
setGeneric("MyFun", function(x, type, ...) standardGeneric("MyFun"), signature="x")
```

(you don't even have to have `type` amongst the arguments to the generic if you don't want to — it depends whether it would be used for other classes of input.)

If you need different other arguments for later algorithms, that is fine. The `...` sorts this out for you. So if you have your two algorithms

```
Algo1<-function(x, M, N){ #blabla }
Algo2<-function(x, F, G, H){ #blablabla }
```

then these will get called correctly when you call

```
MyFun(x,type="Algo1",M=1,N=2) ## dispatched Algo1 with M=1 and N=2
MyFun(x,type="Algo2",F=3,G=4,H=-2.7) ## dispatches Algo2 with F, G and H
```

The recommended way to write the MyFun method is as follows (you were right with your intuition to use `switch`):

```
setMethod("MyFun",signature(x="MyObj"), function(x,type=c("Algo1","Algo2"),...){
  type <- match.arg(type)
  switch(type,
    Algo1=Algo1(x,...),
    Algo2=Algo2(x,...),
    stop("unknown algorithm")
  )
})
```

It would probably be wise to make sure that `Algo1` and `Algo2` do some argument checking to make sure they are receiving the arguments they expect. This is good programming practice in general, but perhaps more important here.

If you haven't come across `match.arg` before, it's the recommended way of ensuring an argument matches one of a defined set of values. It uses the default argument as the list of allowed values.